# Problem with printing and showing string value as plain text

Tags: swift, string, xcode, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I'm trying to show the value of a string as a plain text.

For example if the user writes in George in the textfield it should save as George and only that.
But what happends if i either print it or try to show it in my title it shows like this :
Optional("George")

This is my code

```
   @objc func savefirstname(){ //Saving first name

firstname = usernamefield.text
 UserDefaults.standard.set(firstname, forKey: "firstnamestring");
print(firstname)

    }

  let cellId = "cellId"

    let pages = [
        Page (title: "Thanks for downloading Charity ", body: "Tap on the right side of the screen to continue.")             ,
        Page(title: "Quick registration!  ", body:  "Please enter your first name below."),
        Page(title:"Hello\(firstname)",  body: "Welcome \n\n"),
//When I come to the second page, first name shows like this : HelloOptional("George")
// I want it to show like this: Hello George

    ]
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `usernamefield.text` is an optional value and you have to unwrap it. You could do so, unsafely, with force unwrapping: `firstname = usernamefield.text!`.

Comment: @Eilon I tried it but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Eilon firstname = usernamefield.text! like this

Comment: @Eilon Nevermind, i figured out what you ment. Thank you! You saved a lot of my time:) Such an easy fix.. I feel stupid.

Comment: No problem, I suggest you to study the concept of optionals in swift, it's very important and will help you immensely down the way. Good luck!

Comment: @Eilon Thanks for the advice! I will! I'm very new to swift and just started programming again so its much to learn again haha :)